# sed insert variable after quoted string

Tags: sed, insert

How do I insert a variable after a quoted string in a file using sed?

The variable: `$num`
The quoted string: `"ID": "`

The output in the file would look like: `"ID": "$num`

Answer (score 1):

Use the variable in double quotes.

```
echo '"ID": "' | sed -e "s/^\\(\"ID\": \"\\)/\\1$num"/
```

Note that backslashes need to be backslashed in double quotes. Also, it will only work if $num doesn't contain special characters (e.g. slash).

Comment: An alternative suggestion: `echo '"ID": "' | sed 's/"ID": "/&'$num/`

Comment: Thanks guys. Cyrus, your solution is very efficient, but how to do I dump this back into the file? The original question was to insert the variable after a quoted string in a file. Much thanks...

Comment: Just use the `-i` option to change the file in place.